# Django: Why are my forms' textfields and imagefields never instantiated but all other fields instantiate ok?

Tags: django

My forms' are never fully instantiated, particularly ImageFields (as how they would be like in admin), and TextFields (which appear as  tags)

However, all other fields are instantiated properly.

May I know why this happens?

Attached code that replicates this issue:

```
#view

sellerForm = SellerUpgradeForm(instance=userseller_prof)

#form

class SellerUpgradeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(SellerUpgradeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selling_currency'].queryset = Countries.objects.filter(paypal_valid="yes")
    class Meta:
        model = UserSeller
        fields = ("seller_store_image","shop_description","selling_currency","auth_username",
                  "auth_password","auth_signature")

#model

class UserSeller(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
    access_plan = models.ForeignKey(AccessPlan, verbose_name="Seller's Access Plan")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SELLER_STATUS, verbose_name="Seller Status", default="unapproved")
    rating = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Rating (Upon 5)", decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0)
    total_rating_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Rating Count", default=0)
    selling_currency = models.ForeignKey(Countries, verbose_name="Currency that seller's product will be sold in")
    meta = models.ManyToManyField(UserMeta, verbose_name="User Meta Data", blank=True, related_name="seller_meta")
    shop_description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description about the products you are selling")
    seller_store_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.CUSTOM_UPLOAD_DIR, verbose_name="Store Avatar", blank=True)
    internal_note = models.TextField(verbose_name="Seller Note (Internal Use Only)", blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Created", auto_now_add=True)
    auth_username = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Paypal Auth Username")
    auth_password = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Paypal Auth Password")
    auth_signature = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Paypal Auth Signature")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Seller Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Seller Profiles"
        app_label = "management"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Rating: " + str(self.rating)
```

Comment: Can I assume that by "instantiated" you mean pre-populated?

Comment: essentially, the <textarea> is never pre-populated with instance data. and if i'm not wrong, this is supposed to happen. this occurs through the entire app for every form.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the ImageFields are not pre-populated is a browser security issue, nothing to do with Django.

If browsers let web pages pre-populate file inputs, it would be very easy for a site to arbitrarily upload content from a user's hard drive without their consent. So in order to stop that happening, file input fields are always rendered as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I had a JS script that auto clears textareas on document.ready hence the following. forgot about this.

My bad.